# How to troubleshoot C / C++ not producing output in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++, c

I just followed the set up for C / C++ in VS code ( https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw ), I found two strange things:

1. In the `"tasks.json"` the code has this `"command": "g++"` which is left like that in the site, running the sample source code with that produces this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718765/visual-studio-code-cannot-find-the-g-command-of-my-mingw-w64/51221277 so I followed the solution suggested there and put `"command": "C:\\MinGW64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe"`... and then the thing that I don't get
2. The solution above leaves me with just this in the terminal: `Executing task: C:\MingGW64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -g -o helloworld helloworld.cpp The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1` without any output nor the `helloworld` file, the source code is right, plus it comes directly from the official website.

Sorry if I was too long, any suggestions?

EDIT:  looking through the sample codes for the other files I noticed some differences in c_cpp_properties.json [website's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feuWS.png) [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y0OQ.png) but I don't really understand them, should I add the missing lines?

Comment: "and then the thing that I don't get" - So what exactly is the thing you don't get it?  I suspect you don't understand the reason your compilation is terminted with an exit code.    The output file of the command you indicated you use would have been **helloworld** not **helloworld.exe** by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This output:

```
exit code: 1
```

indicates that the link step failed.

BTW:

You could save yourself a lot of hassle by inputting at a command prompt:

```
g++ -c helloworld.c  -o helloworld.o
```

and when you have corrected any coding problems

```
g++ helloworld.o -o helloworld
```

and when that is successful

```
./helloworld
```

Comment: PS C:\Users\username\projects\helloworld> C:\\MinGW64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe -c helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.o
PS C:\Users\username\projects\helloworld> C:\\MinGW64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe helloworld.o -o helloworld
g++.exe: error: helloworld.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated. This is what I get.

Comment: @Quazar_omega - Why do you have a PowerShell prompt instead of a mingw32 prompt?  Are you using the correct environment in order to run the C++ compiler (i.e. g++)? Due to your inexperience with C++ compilers you might consider an IDE that will make the job easier for you (that clearly is NOT Visual Studio Code), I suggest, the full version of Visual Studio (i.e. Visual Studio Community).

Comment: Well, I understand that as a beginner I could be more comfortable with an IDE. I don't want to seem stubborn for no reason but I am truly intrested in learning how to use this and I am invested in getting to work this helloworld. If I have to learn other things along the way that's just more fun for me, so instead of suggesting a way around it (which I nontheless appriciate) I would prefer to be pointed towards the answer. If there is too much to be explained here, a link to that information would be awesome, and I'll return to this when I know enough.

Comment: anyway I'll check out that IDE as well. Thanks